# Jquery animate HTML5 Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get my video to start at 40% of its original size and once you mouse over it, it animates to 100%. The original size of the div is 760x520 pixels and I need it to start at 300x250 pixels. Heres is the HTML:

```
      <div id="background"> 
         <img src="image/background.jpg" width="760" height="520" style="width:760px;height:520px;position:absolute; top:9px; left:9px;">
         <img src="image/videoPanel02.png" style="width:643px; height:366px;position:absolute;top:62px;left:68px;z-index:inherit;">
         <img src="image/top_bar2.png" style="width:760px;height:60px;position:absolute;top:9px;left:9px;z-index:inherit;">
         <img src="image/bottomMenu_bar.png" style="width:760px;height:45px;position:absolute;top:489px;left:9px;z-index:inherit;">
      <div class="big-player" width="500" height="250" style="width:500px;height:250px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:106px;left:134px;z-index:200;">
        <video width="500" height="250" id="player2" preload="auto">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="http://localhost/HTML5/video/big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
                <object width="500" height="250" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="js/flashmediaelement.swf">
                    <param name="movie" value="js/flashmediaelement.swf" />
                    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=http://localhost/HTML5/video/big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
               </object>
        </video>    
    </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the script I have so far:

```
    var videoplayer;
    var playCount = 0;
    $('video').mediaelementplayer({
    features: ['playpause', 'progress'],
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject, player) {
        videoplayer = player;
        $('.mejs-overlay-button').hide();
        $('.mutebutton').show();
         mediaElement.play();
         player.setMuted(true);
        //show poster image once the video stops and video restarts
        mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            $('.image-end').show(); 
            playCount++;
            if(playCount>=3){
                player.pause();
            }

        },false); //end ended function
    }//close success
});//close mediaelementplayer

$('#background').each(function(){
    $(this).width($(this).width() * 0.5);
});

$('#background').mouseover(function() {
    videoplayer.setMuted(false);
     $("#background").animate({
        width:"100%",
    }, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: you need to look at doing the video tag size the background will go 100% or what ever set but its the video tag you need to target and set. Else set th etag to 100% and give the background a fixed size and do it that way etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U2mQH/1/) give you some clue.

```
$(function () {
    $("#video")
        .on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: 500,
            height: 500
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Im going to give that a try Thanks

Comment: if you put your function in `ready` method than your javascript function waits for DOM  to fully load. Until that time your mouseover event will not be triggered. DOMs loading may takes some time related with your video file.

Comment: Will that make it so there is a delay on the animation? I put the animate in my code and now there is a delay once I mouseenter.